# Facebook - Do you need a Facebook Application / appid to call FB.ui(stream.publish)?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I would like to add a button to my website so when people click it, they will post a message to their facebook status feed with a message (I'm OK with they having to approve it). `FB.ui` and `stream.publish` look like exactly what I want.

The [Facebook documentation for FB.init](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init) states that:

> Note: Some UI methods like stream.publish and stream.share can be used without registering an application or calling this method.

So I don't need to register a Facebook application, brilliant. However I can't get `FB.ui(… 'stream.publish…)` to work. The popup window says "An error occurred. Please try again later.". I am not using FB.init, nor using an appid. (All this is done in JavaScript).

There is some [notes on the web that you now need an app id to use stream.publish](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=270044#p270044). is this true? Do you need an appid to use stream.publish?

My code is this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#share_on_facebook").click(function() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'stream.publish',
      message: 'Check out this great app! http://apps.facebook.com/{your_app}'
    });
  });
});
```

I can call `stream.share` without needing an appid (as the documentation says). It's just `stream.publish` that I can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it might be possible.  Check out this example:

http://fbrell.com/fb.ui/stream.publish

Comment: That example is no longer available ?!?